# What is the usage of "would" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

> I want to write in great length to you, but I am afraid that I **would** be a bother to you this evening.

Comment: Can you tell more about what you're not understanding? "Would" is a [conditional tense of "will"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would).

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused about whether "would" is used to make statements sound less direct or tentative in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [conditional](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/) constructions can make a statement or request more indirect, less blunt ("Excuse me, would you have change for a dollar?"). But in this case it's also used because the speaker is talking about something imagined, something that has not and probably will not happen. "I **want** to write—" but I won't—because maybe "I **would** be a bother." (If I did write.) The writing discussed is an imaginary event. This is the situation referred to in the link above as "Type 2 Conditional."

Comment: Thanks. Is it also correct if I replace **would** with **will**? I want to write in great lenght to you, but I'm afraid that I **will** be a bother to you this evening

Comment: Also, what's the difference between "would" and " is"? Life **would** be quieter without the telephone. Life **is** quieter without the telephone

Comment: @Cocommentator No, it wouldn't be strictly right to say "I want to write... but I'm afraid that I *will* be a bother"; "would" is better because it's still hypothetical. Your second question helps explain it: the difference between "would" and "is" depends on whether you're describing reality or not. If you got rid of your telephone, you could say "Life **is** quieter without it." If you still have it, and are *thinking* of getting rid of it, then you can say "Life **would be** quieter without it."

Comment: I stil don't uderstand. Could you explain more clearly? In my English grammar book says that "would” is used to make a statement sound less direct and "is" sounds direct.  So, in the sentence "life **would** be quieter with the telephone" and "life is quieter without the telephone", is this the difference between less direct and direct? The speaker isn't sure that life **is** quieter without it, whereas the use of "is" sounds dogmatic. Is my understanding right?